# Calling a schedule service webservice from groovy without hardcoding userID and password values in oracle cx sales

Tags: oracle, web-services, groovy, soap

Steps I have fallowed:

1)I have registered a soap webservice i.e., schedule service and I have to given Propagate User Identity using SAML as security scheme
`Name -scheduleService`
`Url - https://xxx-xxx/xmlpserver/services/v2/ScheduleService?WSDL`

2)Writing Groovy in object function that schedules the report
Script -

```
def userID = 'xxxxxxxx'
    def password = 'xxxxxxx'
    def scheduleRequest = [ 
    bookBindingOutputOption: false, 
    compressDeliveryOutputOption: false, 
    dataModelUrl: "/shared/Custom/DataImport/Person_Detail_DM.xdm", //path of dm                                        
    mergeOutputOption: false, 
    notifyHttpWhenFailed: true, 
    notifyHttpWhenSkipped: true, 
    notifyHttpWhenSuccess: true, 
    notifyHttpWhenWarning: true, 
    notifyWhenFailed: false, 
    notifyWhenSkipped: true, 
    notifyWhenSuccess: false, 
    notifyWhenWarning: false, 
    repeatCount: 0, 
    repeatInterval: 0, 
    deliveryChannels: [ 
    wccOptions: [ 
      item: [ 
        [  
          WCCComments: "Report Job created via ScheduleService", 
          WCCFileName: 'test', 
          WCCFolderPath: "/Contribution Folders/CRM/", 
          WCCIncludeMetadata: true, 
          WCCSecurityGroup: "CRMStage", 
          WCCServerName: "FA_UCM_PROVISIONED", 
          WCCTitle: 'test', 
        ] 
      ], 
     ], 
   ], 
    reportRequest: [ 
    attributeCalendar: "Gregorian", 
    attributeLocale: "en-US", 
    attributeFormat: "csv", 
    //attributeTemplate: "CDM_HZ_TREE_NODE-LYT", 
    byPassCache: true, 
    flattenXML: false, 
    reportAbsolutePath: "/Custom/DataImport/Person_Details_REP.xdo", 
    sizeOfDataChunkDownload: -1 
    ], 
    saveDataOption: true, 
    saveOutputOption: true, 
    scheduleBurstringOption: true, 
    scheduleBurstingOption: true, 
    schedulePublicOption: true, 
    useUTF8Option: true, 
    userJobDesc: "My Test Report", 
    userJobName: "MyReport" 
    ] 
    def submittedJobId 
    def Counter = 0 
    try { 
     **def submittedJobIdOut=adf.webServices.scheduleService.scheduleReport(scheduleRequest,UseID,password)**
     println("submittedJobIdOut"+submittedJobIdOut)
      for (i in 1..950000) { 
      Counter = Counter + 1 
     } 
    **def JobStatusOut=adf.webServices.testSchedule.getScheduledReportStatus(submittedJobIdOut,UseID,password)
**     println(JobStatusOut)
      def val = JobStatusOut.toString() 
      def JobStatus = substringAfter(val, 'jobStatus:') 
      def JobStatus1 = substringBefore(JobStatus, ',') 
      println('JobStatus1' + JobStatus1)
      }catch(e){
      println(e)
      }
```

3. I wanted above service to run without userID and password variables
   inserting the webservice from pallet will automatically give userID and password in the groovy script.
4. I have also tried with removing userID and password from groovy script but it was giving an exception that schedule report cant run with these parameters

I wanted -
Calling a schedule service webservice from groovy without hardcoding userID and password values in oracle cx sales by any security scheme`